# IP address in wrong country

Tags: ip-address

I just setup a VPS and everything went well. But I randomly decided to get some info about my IP address.

The info I found said that my IP address was assigned to Germany, I and the company I set everything up for are in the US.

What are the SEO implications of this? Can it be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get this info from?  There are various databases that offer opinions about where a particular IP is physically located.  They may be inconsistent or wrong.

Those services may have a form by which you can tell them about incorrect results.

Comment: somewhere that didn't look viable. it just got me concerned. Is there a reputable place that I can look into this?

Comment: As I say, there are lots of them.  One service that I believe to be reputable is [GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location).  There is a [web form](http://www.geoiptool.com/) where you can try it out.

Comment: I used it and several others. You are spot on, it is very inconsistent. Thanks for the help! +1

Answer (score 1):

SEO does not care one tiny bit about the IP address your are hosted on.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help guys! +1

Comment: That's not true - Google ranks sites in the same country as you higher in some situations (notably businesses). So if you search using www.google.co.uk it then a site based in the UK with either a UK TLD or a UK IP will rank higher than a US one assuming other factors are the same. See this link which includes an official Google response confirming this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=2e61e49baa5a6eaf

Comment: @Rafiq - `however, if your site *has a geographic TLD/ccTLD* (like .co.nz) then we *will not use the location of the server* as well.` - you should always have a localised TLD anyway, so if you've done your marketing correctly, the IP address is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, the TLD is given more importance than the IP location, but it is still more relevant to SEO than "not one tiny bit". And if you're doing business in the US, you are likely to NOT have a localised TLD and rather have a .com which is ignored by Google for determining location - IP address applies in the case of com/net/org